# How DataFrame Size cached in Memory Affect Processing time in Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I was experimenting with, what is the maximum raw data that i can cache without affecting overall processing time for a Job in Spark.

Spark Cluster - 2 machines, 12 Cores, 96GB Ram. I have create 12 Workers each with 1 Core and 8GB Ram.

I have cached a parquet of ~2.4GB which create a memory footprint of around 5.4GB on RAM. On Simple task its taking ~8 sec (Count --> GroupBY --> Collect).

I have again cached 6 similar files, each parquet of ~2.4GB which create a total memory footprint of around ~30GB. again performing same task (Count--> GroupBY --> Collect) on loaded 5.4GB cached dataframe its taking ~12 sec.

data is mix of (date , timestamp , string , double ) fields ~300 columns in each file.

**Already Tried -**

Case 1 - Total Executors - 4 , Each Executor Cores - 3 cores ,  Each Executor Memory 24GB

Case 2 - Total Executors - 6 , Each Executor Cores - 2 cores ,  Each Executor Memory 16GB

Case 3 - Total Executors - 12 , Each Executor Cores - 1 cores ,  Each Executor Memory 8GB

**Case 3** is giving me best results.

**is this correct behaviour for spark?**

Spark v2.0.2